# Why does $\overline{\alpha * \beta}=\bar{\beta} * \bar{\alpha}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm working on this question from Munkres' topology:

Let $\alpha$ be a path in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$; let $\beta$ be a path in $X$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$. Show that if $\gamma = \alpha * \beta$ , then $\bar{\gamma}$= $\bar{\beta} \circ \bar{\alpha}$.

I can answer this questioin I just need help with one step, how would I show that
$$\overline{\alpha * \beta}=\bar{\beta} * \bar{\alpha}$$

Thanks!

Comment: What does the bar mean? Homotopy class? What do the different prooducts $*$ and $\circ$ mean?

Comment: Sorry- the bar is meant to mean the  "reverse", so $\bar{\alpha}(t) = \alpha(1-t)$

Comment: Your equation should be $\overline{\alpha * \beta} = \bar \beta * \bar \alpha$, right?

Comment: Anyway, you should just define the composition of the paths piece-wise and replace $t$ by $1-t$ everywhere.

Comment: $\circ$ is the composition of functions

Comment: Composition here does not make sense since the domain and range don't match, I think you just mean $*$ both places.

Comment: Does this work?$\overline{\alpha * \beta} = (\alpha * \beta)(1-t)=\alpha(1-t)*\beta(1-t)=\overline{\alpha}(t)*\overline{\beta}(t)= \overline{\beta} *\overline{\alpha}$

Comment: It does not work, the symbol $\alpha(t)*\beta(t)$ has no meaning. And you are using to notation for different things, $\alpha*\beta$ with no $t$ mean the concatenation and $\alpha*\beta(t)$ is a point. You can not just mix it

Comment: And think that the easier way is calculation both concatenation.

Comment: $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ holds for all $a,b$ in a group $G$

Comment: @anon This does not quite work here since the set of paths does not form a group, the set of homotopy classes of paths does.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\overline{\alpha * \beta}(t) = (\alpha * \beta)(1-t) &= \begin{cases} \alpha(2(1 - t)) & 0 \leq 1-t \leq 1/2 \\ \beta(2(1-t)-1) & 1/2 \leq 1-t \leq 1 \end{cases} 
 \\ &=\begin{cases} \alpha(2 - 2t) & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1 \\ \beta(1 - 2t) & 0 \leq t \leq 1/2 \end{cases} 
 \\ &= \begin{cases} \bar{\beta}(2t) & 0 \leq t \leq 1/2  \\ \bar{\alpha}(2t - 1) & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases} 
 \\ &= (\overline{\beta}*\overline{\alpha})(t)\end{align}$$

This shows that $\overline{\alpha * \beta} = \overline{\beta} * \overline{\alpha}$ $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

This exercise can be done by direct computation of $\overline{\alpha*\beta}$ and $\bar\alpha*\bar\beta$. Compare the result and conclude that they are the same.

Comment: But how would I compute them?

Comment: Use the definition, you do not need more. What is the definition of that multiplication?